# Uso di consonante 'b' raddoppiata nella pronuncia romana dell'italiano

Tags: regional, pronunciation

Forse dipende dal mio orecchio non abituato, ma secondo voi i romani usano raddoppiare la 'b' in parole come 'robba', 'nubbi', 'vibbra' e altre ancora o, appunto, è solo una mia impressione?

Comment: C'è da chiederlo? :-)

Comment: @DaG È che quando sento le previsioni del tempo alla Rai, dove si parla di 'nubbi', non riesco a non piegarmi in due per i crampi.

Comment: Questo mi dispiace molto, ma forse più che questo dovresti consultare un sito di gastroenterologia. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Molti raddoppiamenti intervocalici sono tipici del dialetto romano e della varietà romana dell'italiano (e di conseguenza spesso anche della pronuncia romana dell'italiano standard).

La migliore illustrazione è data dai sonetti del Belli, in cui abbondano “giubbileo”, “subbito”, “abbitava”, “abbati” (e anche all'inizio della parola, specie dopo una vocale: “cquanno bbutta”, ma anche isolatamente: “Bbravo!”).

Comment: Giuro che ho sentito la seguente conversazione per strada a Roma: «Ahò, ma ebbete co' qquante bbi se scrive?» «Co' ddu bbi, si nun vado erato»

Comment: In romanesco si scrive senz'altro co' du' bbi! (E, giustamente, le erre si scempiano: *tera*, *guera*, *erore* etc.)

Comment: (E fatemi fare per un attimo il pedante. Vi ricordo che i dialetti non sono versioni sbagliate di un'altra lingua: sono lingue che non si sono affermate a livello nazionale. Come si suol dire, «una lingua è un dialetto con un esercito e una marina». Quello che semmai è “sbagliato” – ma bisogna sempre stare attentissimi a parlare di “errori” in linguistica – è pensare di parlare italiano standard quando invece si manifestano influenze locali.)

Comment: Non intendevo prendere in giro il romanesco (che per forza di cose influenza anche il mio modo di parlare, non tanto col raddoppio delle bi quanto coll'ammorbidimento delle ci, di cui evidentemente mi rendo meno conto), ma far fare una risatina con l'incontro delle due variazioni di segno contrario (_ebbete_ e _erato_), e anche con l'effetto curioso che fa chi è immerso in un dialetto senza rendersene conto. Non credo che la domanda fosse con quante bi si scriva ebete in romanesco...

Comment: Qui sorge la mia domanda: è chiaro che i dialetti dell'italiano sono lingue a sé, vista la storia linguistica della penisola. Mi chiedo se però il romanesco si qualifichi in questo senso come lingua o piuttosto come una variante dell'italiano, indi del toscano. Ovviamente la distinzione non è netta, ma mentre altri dialetti hanno una struttura grammaticale propria, il romanesco può altrettanto dirsi lingua a sé?

Comment: @martina: Non usavo lingua in un senso specifico contrapposto a dialetto, anzi: intendevo proprio che tutti gli idiomi, varianti l'uno dell'altro, parlati in una nazione hanno un'uguale dignità, e sono solo gli eventi storici che ci fanno sentire uno come più corretto o di maggior prestigio, mentre gli altri possono suonare come storpiature. E non era certo un rimprovero a Walter, di cui ho anche upvotato il commento.

Comment: @martina (2): Quanto al resto, anche se meno macroscopiche di altri dialetti/varianti, anche il romanesco ha le sue peculiarità morfologiche (una per tutte: le desinenze differenziate per i verbi alla 1ª persona plurale -amo, -emo, -imo, anziché tutte in -iamo) e sintattiche, e non solo lessicali. Prova a prendere qualche sonetto del Belli e a trasformarlo esclusivamente dal punto di vista del lessico (cioè al posto di “bbono” metti “buono” etc.), e vedi se viene fuori italiano standard. :-)

Comment: Lo so, è certamente interessante. Andiamo fuori tema, ma credo che una risposta si possa dare se si guarda a se il romanesco è preesistente o coesistente con quello che poi divenne l'italiano (cosa che vale per i dialetti che chiamiamo lingue).